# Visual Studio XML comments: what to specify for Equals, GetHashCode etc?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I like the XML comments of Visual Studio much. I wonder if there is a special way to comment inherited basic methods like `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` in order to take over the description of the object class.

E.g. MSDN just says

> Determines whether the specified Object is equal to the current
>   Object. (Inherited from Object.)

For all occurences of `Equals()`. Can I do the same with XML comments?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install an auto-comment tool, like [GhostDoc (http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx), they will generally pull the existing comments from the abstract class or interface that defines the overridden/implemented members.

For instance, when implementing `IDisposable`, GhostDoc generates these comments for `Dispose()`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
/// </summary>
```

HTH.